# Greediness of preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

```
echo preg_replace('/:*$/isD', ':', ':blue:');
```

A fairly simple PHP regex, which is designed to capture as many colons at the end of a string as possible (there may not be any at all) and replace it with just one. Or at least that's what I set out to do.

Here's the output:

```
:blue::
```

I expected, since `preg_replace` is greedy, that the colon at the end of the string would be captured, and thus I would get

```
:blue:
```

instead.

Oddly, using similar code to check for colons at the *beginning* of a string (i.e. `/^(:)*/isD`) works. I'm guessing this has something to do with the fact that regexes search from left to right, so in the non-working end of string example, it's finding only the end of the string, whereas in the working front of string example, it's already found the beginning of the string.

That said, what I can do to make `preg_replace` capture all of the ending colons?

Comment: How about `rtrim($string, ":");`?

Comment: @WesleyvanOpdorp That's definitely an open option; it's just that this is the only part of a longer regex that isn't quite working as I planned, and if I'm just doing something stupid here that can be easily fixed, I'd rather just fix the regex. If the problem is more complex than that, `rtrim` is probably what I'm going to end up using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace('/:+$/isD', ':', ':blue:');
```

just replace the `*` (means zero or more) by a `+` (means one or more).

The `*` matches at first all colons till the end and then the empty string, so there are two matches.

**Update**

To ensure exactly one colon at the end, you can use this:

```
echo preg_replace('/^(.*?):*$/isD', '$1:', ':blue');
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the string won't necessarily always contain a colon at the end. Sorry!

Comment: Does that mean, if there is no colon at the end you want to put one there?

Comment: Correct, I want to guarantee exactly one colon at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the `*` with `+` so that the empty string is not matched:

```
echo preg_replace('/:+$/isD', ':', ':blue:');
```

yields

```
:blue:
```

**Update**

Consider using a variant of `trim`, that makes it a little more "light-weight":

```
echo rtrim(":blue:::::", ":") . ":";
```

This will remove all the `:` from the end and add one `:`, as you desired.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the string won't necessarily always contain a colon at the end. Sorry!